# Entity Framework - Date Range

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I have a MVC application with a grid on the view.  The user is allowed to filter the data on the grid using different information.  One way is to use two datepickers for date range (min/max).  I attempting to find all matching datasets in the business logic.  But for some reason the date range always returns a empty set.  I know I don't have it coded right, but not sure what to change.  This is the code -

```
filteredbyCustCriteria = _unitOfWork.CustomerRepository.Get.Where
(w => (reportSearch.FullName != null ? (w.FirstName + " " + w.LastName).Contains(reportSearch.FullName.Trim()) : true)
&& (reportSearch.MinPaidDate != null ? EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(w.Orders.FirstOrDefault().OrderPayments.FirstOrDefault().PaymentDate) >= reportSearch.MinPaidDate : true)
&& (reportSearch.MaxPaidDate != null ? EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(w.Orders.FirstOrDefault().OrderPayments.FirstOrDefault().PaymentDate) <= reportSearch.MaxPaidDate : true));
```

It works find on the fullname.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When working with nullable `DateTime` I find that I have to use `.Value` in certain cases. Try this:

```
>= reportSearch.MinPaidDate.Value
<= reportSearch.MaxPaidDate.Value
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, though it still did not return any records

Comment: Have you profiled the SQL output to make sure it makes sense? BTW, I'd write the LINQ more like this `(reportSearch.MinPaidDate == null || EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(w.Orders.FirstOrDefault().OrderPayments.FirstOrDefault().PaymentDate) >= reportSearch.MinPaidDate.Value)`